# How to display HTML content without webview in android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I want to display HTML content in my app without using `webview`. HTML data may contain the text (including style), image, table, etc. Is there any library for this? I have read about HTML parser but if I use this I will have to create each view dynamically. Instead of that is there any other solution? Need help on this.

Answer (score 4):

For HTML with images and basic text formatting you can use `Html.fromHtml()` ([API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))) and display the result in a `TextView` instance.

To display images, you will have to implement the [Html.ImageGetter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html) interface, to load image references and convert them to `Drawable`.

Tables are trickier. You can implement the [Html.TagHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) interface to detect table related tags and decide how to display them, but proper layout of table data can get quite complicated very easily. If your HTML tables are relatively simple - columns and rows with small values, but no cells spanning multiple columns or rows - then it might be feasible to implement a tag handler that collates the table data and displays it in basic columns.

Alternatively, it might be simpler to use something like this https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview